# How to avoid spacing from the first div of each row

Tags: html, css

I have `DIVs` which comes `side by side` of each other & but there only `fourth DIV` comes in the first `row` & other are shifted too the next `row`.

I want each `row` `first div` take no space from `left side` but is not happened. Here is my code

### http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/

I know i can do it with giving `class` manual to the `new row DIV` but i didn't want that. i want this with less css & i didn't want to change my `markup`

*NOTE*:   i want capability till IE8.

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATED:

### http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/8/

First the `.parent` div is a `common class` which is used in other section also & second thing according to the design the `parent DIVs` touch the `row last div` so, there is no space from the right side.

Comment: .feature {
margin-right: 16px;
}, also remove margin-left from .feature + .feature

Comment: I can't work out exactly what you're trying to do. Could you explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Suggestion A:**

Add `margin-left:-16px` to parent

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/1/

**Suggestion B:**

Use `margin-right: 16px` on the inner divs, instead of `margin-left`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/4/

**Suggestion C:**

If the parent div width is fixed, you can remove margin on every [4th child](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) like this:

```
.feature:nth-child(4n){
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/15/

**Suggestion d:**

Wrap your inner divs in a wrapper, and set this to be wider that the parent div

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/17/

Comment: Note that in the question it says "i want capability till IE8".

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using negative margin and padding. In feature class use `margin-right:16px` and remove **.feature + .feature** class.

so your css will be

```
.parent{
    width:480px;
}
.feature{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;  
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:16px;
}
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/25pwG/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
    width:480px;
    text-align: center;
}
.feature{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;  
    margin:0 6px 10px;
}
```

I suggest trying this one. Using a negative value might cause some  problems later on. So as much as possible avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, just change from

```
.feature + .feature { margin-left:16px; } /*Remove this*/
```

to

```
.feature { margin-right:16px; }
```